# AMQP Qpid Proton - Unable to send messages to more than 256 queues

Tags: java, activemq-classic, amqp, qpid

I am using AMQP 1.0 with Qpid Proton 0.6 and ActiveMQ 5.9.0 as a broker.

When sending messages to less than 256 queues everything is ok.

When sending messages to more than 256 Proton blocks after 256 queue.

```
Messenger mng = new MessengerImpl();
mng.start();

for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    Message message = new MessageImpl();
    String address = "amqp://localhost:5672/queue://receiver";
    message.setAddress(address+i);
    message.setBody(new AmqpValue("test message"));                   
    mng.put(message);
}        

mng.send();
mng.stop();
```

The same situation occurs on Proton non blocking mode.

Is it a Proton limitation or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: First thing to do is try it against a 5.10-SNAPSHOT build, we've been working hard to make AMQP better for the next release.

Comment: Unfortunately the same happens using latest 5.10-SNAPSHOT (5.10 is using proton 0.6 instead of 0.5 but this not solve the problem)

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no known issue with Proton or ActiveMQ in this regard so it look like you might have uncovered a bug.  The best course of action is to create a Jira issue with either project to allow it to be tracked down.

Whenever reporting bugs to open-source projects its a good idea to include a unit test so the developers can quickly see the use case and start analysing it.